# Array Size Declarations

Tags: c++

Suppose we are given an array a[10] such that it contains both even and odd numbers. We have to move the even elements to another array say b[10] and odd elements(numbers) to array c[10]. the numbers in array are to be entered by the user which means we do not know the exact number of even and odd elements present in a. L
Suppose there are 5 even numbers that will go in array b[10].For remaining 5 it will print some garbage value. 
I want that the garbage value should not be printed

Comment: Keep track of how many elements you added to each array.  Or just use `std::vector`, which does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most straightforward way to accomplish this would be to maintain two counts to track how many items you inserted into the `b` and `c` arrays.  Note that you will have to do this anyway in order to know where to insert the next item.

For example, you might declare `b_count` and `c_count` variables and initialize them to zero.  If the number is even you write the number to `b[b_count]` and then add 1 to `b_count`, and the same thing for `c` and `c_count` if the number is odd.

Then you loop from 0 up to (but not including) the count variable of whatever array you want to enumerate.

---

I have not written any code here as I suspect this is a homework question and I do not want to spoonfeed the OP complete and working code.

Comment: will this prevent printing of garbage value?

Comment: @sahilsikka Think about it.  If you keep track of how many elements you have added, and only print up to that many elements, is it possible to access the uninitialized (garbage) elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the *size of contents* of each array like this:

```
int a[10], b[10], c[10];
int b_length = 0, c_length = 0;

...

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
        b[b_length++] = a[i];
    else
        c[c_length++] = a[i];
}
```

or you can use `std::vector`. It is *more* C++.

```
std::vector<int> b, c;

...

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
        b.push_back(a[i]);
    else
        c.push_back(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: The size of each array is 10.

Comment: @juanchopanza ...so what? what do you want to say?

Comment: "You can save the size of each array like this:" What do you think?

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh, I think there was some ambiguous point; I edited.